# Why is the "new" keyword not necessary in Swift?

Tags: swift

Why is the `new` keyword not necessary in Swift?

In other languages such as Java or C#, `new` is necessary to allocate memory for a each new object.
Ex.

```
(Foo) foo = new Foo()
```

However in swift, it's

```
(var) foo = Foo()
```

If Swift has built in garbage collection/memory allocation, is `new` implicit, or is it simply not used. If the latter, why/what replaces it?

Comment: Swift uses [automatic reference counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Comment: It's just that swift compiler is smarter than the java/c#, it recognises what we want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For heap-allocated/reference types (`class`es), Swift utilizes **Automatic Reference Counting**: rather than requiring explicit calls to `delete`, memory is deallocated when the last "strong" reference to it disappears. `var foo = Foo()` or `let foo = Foo()` allocates and initializes an instance of the `Foo` class, and creates a local variable with a strong reference to it. When this variable goes out of scope, if no other references have been made, the object is deallocated.

From [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html):

> Every time you create a new instance of a class, ARC allocates a chunk of memory to store information about that instance. This memory holds information about the type of the instance, together with the values of any stored properties associated with that instance.
>
> Additionally, when an instance is no longer needed, ARC frees up the memory used by that instance so that the memory can be used for other purposes instead. This ensures that class instances do not take up space in memory when they are no longer needed.

You can also read about the [initialization sequence](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html), i.e. the interactions between properties and custom `init`s in a class hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

`new` is just a language construct that says I want to initialize and create a new Foo.  If the compiler is smart enough to determine that that's what you want to do from the context, why be verbose about it?  The bottom line is that there's really no functional difference between:

```
[[Foo alloc] init] - Objective C
[Foo new] - Objective C
new Foo() - C/C++/Java
Foo() - Swift
```

Also note that in C++, you can use the following to generate a stack-based object:

```
Foo foo();
```

ARC, reference counting, garbage collection, explicit delete, are all just mechanisms for reclaiming memory used by objects that are no longer needed, and really have no bearing on the language syntax necessary to create an object in the first place.

Don't get hung up on syntax, learn to recognize constructs and operations, and then attach syntax to constructs and you're 90% of the way to knowing every programming language out there.

Comment: Easy to read masses of code and gain insightful logic with "new" keyword though :-/